# C# constructor using this

Tags: c#

Can somebody explain what means `: this(123)` in a constructor ?

```
public class MyObject
{      
    public MyObject(): this(123)
    {
    }
    ............
}
```

Comment: do you perhaps have a `MyObject(int variable){ }` constructor?

Comment: You can read about constructors [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Why don't you step through the code with a debugger to see what it does?

Comment: Did you [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+constructor+this)? We already have some answers that might have worked for you.

Comment: I will guess that when I instantiate a new object MyObject, the int parameter is somehow optional but by default set to 123 (like you will make an optional parameter in a method: public void Method(int val =5)) ...

Comment: this means call of overloaded class constructor which take in one integer parameter.

Comment: Yep I have another constructor, so basically when I call new MyObject() then it will call my second constructor MyObject(int val) with the value 123 ... I got it!

Comment: See [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx), near the bottom, where it says: *A constructor can invoke another constructor in the same object by using the `this` keyword. ...*

Comment: Let me SymbolHound that for you http://symbolhound.com/?q=c%23+%3A+this%28 (but seriously, that site is extremely useful for searching for symbols and other words that are hard to google)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your class has another constructor which takes and `int` as parameter.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject()
        : this(123)
    {
    }

    public MyObject(int x) //something like this
    {
    }
}
```

See: [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx)

> A constructor can invoke another constructor in the same object by
>   using the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

This means, that you are calling another constructor with the fixed Value "123":

```
public class MyObject
{      
    public MyObject(): this(123)
    {

    }

    public MyObject(int number)
    {

    }
}
```

Means: Whenever you call `new MyObject()`, without any parameter, it equals the call to `new MyObject(123);`

Comment: *"it equals the call to new MyObject(123);"* Not really.. there can be stuff in the default constructor that is not executed in the other constructors

Comment: In this example, there is nothing in the constructors, so it's equal :P

Answer (score 1):

this is used to call one constructor from another within the same class. 
Refer to this article for better understanding.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7011/An-Intro-to-Constructors-in-C

Answer (score 1):

You have another constructor that accepts an int (thought it could be long or double, or anything else that int can implicitly cast to)

```
    public class MyObject
    {      
       public MyObject(): this(123)
       {
       }

       public MyObject(int num)
       {
          //do something with the num
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**That means** *"before you execute what between the curly brackets, execute the suitable Constructor with parameters `123`"*

Answer (score 0):

The syntax provided is used for "constructor chaining" whereby the specified constructor (which accepts an integer argument) is called before the body of the current constructor.